# Solving Chinese Remainder Theorem Help

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need some help finishing up this CRT calculation. So far I have

$$x\equiv 0 \pmod {49}$$
$$x\equiv -1 \pmod {121}$$
$$x\equiv -2 \pmod {169}$$
$$x\equiv -3 \pmod {289}$$
$$x\equiv 53424 \pmod {190969}$$

so first I choose to solve

$$x\equiv -3 \pmod {289}$$
$$x\equiv 53424 \pmod {190969}$$

So I used the extended euclidean alg to find the solution to
1 = 190969*s + 289*t
and got 1 = 190969(-53) + 289(35022)

so then $$1\equiv 289*(35022) \pmod{190969}$$ 
and then 
x = 289k - 3
$$289k\equiv 53427 \pmod{190969}$$ ?

But I get stuck at this point and can't properly find x?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your prior two questions.

Answer (score 0):

We write $x=53424+m\times 190969$ and we want to find $m$ so that $x\equiv -3 \pmod {289}$.  Thus we want $$248+229m\equiv -3\pmod {289}\implies 251 \equiv 60m\pmod {289}$$  This is easily solved to get $m\equiv 9\pmod {289}$

Finally we get $$x= 53424+9\times 190969 = \boxed {1772145}$$

Comment: im sorry how did you get 248 + 229m = -3 mod 289?

Comment: $x=53424 + 190969m$ and $53424 \equiv 248$, $190969\equiv 229$.

Comment: also I dont understand how you got 251 = 60m I swear everyhwere I look people do the CRT differently im so confused

Comment: As a suggestion:  you seem to be struggling with the basic operations of modular arithmetic.  Given that, why work such a messy problem?  Start with smaller numbers and build up from there.

Comment: Im not sure how I am supposed to solve this then the numbers get so big and almost impossible to work with

Comment: That's why I propose working with smaller numbers until you gain confidence.  To be clear:  $289$ is fairly small!  A bit outside comfort zone with pen and paper, but only a bit.  You ought to be able to solve $ax+b\equiv c \pmod {289}$.  Focus on that first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method for k residues $(a_i)$ and k modulus $(m_i)$. Let $m=m_1 m_2 \cdot \cdot \cdot m_k$ and consider $m/m_1$. This is relatively prime to $m_1$, so there exists an integer $t_1$ such that $t_1\cdot m/m_1 \equiv 1 $ (mod $m_1$). Accordingly, let $s_1=t_1\cdot m/m_1$. Then $s_1 \equiv 1$ (mod $m_1$) and $s_1 \equiv 0$ (mod $m_j$), $j\not =1$. Similarly, for all i, there exists an $s_i$ such that $s_i \equiv 1$ (mod $m_i$) and $s_i \equiv 0$ (mod $m_j$), $j\not =i$. Then $x=a_1s_1+a_2s_2+...+a_ks_k$ is a solution for the system.

You already had $m_1=289$, $a_1=-3$, $t_1=-53$ and $m_2=190969$, $a_2=53424$, $t_2=35022$. Therefore, $x=35022\cdot 53424+ (-3)\cdot(-53)=1871015487$

But $190969(-3)+289(35022)=9548451$ so the numbers you gave must be wrong.